# Creating UI component for my tests

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I run my test using Java, Selenium and TestNG.

When I execute my test suite I have it set up where the `testng.xml` has all the configurations to run my tests. I am wondering, if I can set up my own custom UI component that does the same thing as the xml?

I am asking because I have nontechnical people in my staff and I don't want them to have to download an IDE, check out the project, etc. I want to create some UI where they can just go there and hit a button and the tests runs just like how I can right click on the `testng.xml` and hit run.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a build tool like Jenkins: https://jenkins.io/.  This would allow other users to visit a webpage to run the tests instead of using an IDE - as long as they don't need to modify testng.xml.